# ui grid fetch data on demand when user scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I am currently using version 3 of UI-Grid.(http://ui-grid.info/), I have implemented infinite scroll as project requirements. Now the requirement changes, we want to have the vertical scroll bar to reflect the total items in data set, e.g if data set is 100 items, the scroll bar should be larger when data set is 10000 items. When user scroll the bar, I need to fetch the data based on where did user scroll, so it achieve lazy loading, as our data set is usually really large. 
I would like to ask if it is possible to achieve in ui-grid.

I think ui-grid has no control on the scroll bar anymore as in version 3. For the implementation, I will need to know, for given the size of dataset, I can set the scroll bar properties. And when isVerticalScrolling=false, I will need to do a RESTful call to server to fetch the data.

Does anyone created similar function before? Or have any idea how to implement it?

**Update:**
What behaviour do I want to achieve. [image]

[image]

The scroll bar is responsive, and I want to be able to set it in Javascript. 
Then comes with the problem, how I can retrieve the value of the scroll bar.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you are trying to achieve -- I'm confused on your description of "if data set is 100 items, the scroll bar should be larger when data set is 10000 items". For reference, angular material has a nice set of virtual scroll examples; can you tell me which one you are trying to implement? I think you are trying to do what they call "Deferred Loading" but I want to make sure you're not trying to do what they call "Infinite Scroll": https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

Comment: Thanks for reply, very appreciated. Firstly, I surely don't want to do infinite scroll any more. Secondly, I have to stick with ui-grid, so no other data grid framework. Thirdly, for you to understand better I am updating the description with a detail explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the pictures -- that helps a lot. Btw, I wasn't suggesting you use angular material, I just wanted you to compare what they had to what you are wanting so I can understand better. Anyways, if you know the amount of items that you have in the list and the height of each item, you can set the total height of the scrollable content and the scrollbar should take care of itself. To get the value you just use the scrollTop property of your element. Does this help at all?

Comment: Whoops, I completely forgot you are specifically asking about this in ui-grid. I don't think it supports something like this, yet.